# No VPN is running. What does this mean?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have installed `openvpn` using the command :

```
sudo apt-get install  openvpn
```

After installing it, when I tried to start it, I get:

```
* Reloading virtual private network daemon(s)... 
 *   No VPN is running.
```

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I couldn't able to get what `No VPN is running.` meant.  Does this mean any thing wrong in my installation?

I'm using 12.04 Ubuntu Version and since openvpn uses, tun/tap, I wonder its already installed in 12.04 versions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw. with `sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc` you can easily install a graphical tool to configure your virtual private network connections from within the unity task bar.

Comment: I have installed this, how do I open it?

Comment: That was just a remark for convenience. You don't really open it, you can find it with the network-manager tray icon, like in this picture: http://i.imgur.com/DJXkE.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your installation. You see this message because you haven't set up any VPN. You've installed the program, but you haven't yet set it up to be used. If you configure one or more VPN to automatically start at boot time, instead of this message, you'll see the nicknames of each VPN as it starts up.

Comment: oh! So how one could find the current running process in Ubuntu? So that I can check `openvpn` is running. . .

Comment: `ps -A | grep -i vpn` in shell would show you which processes are running that have "vpn" in their name.

Comment: @batman If you haven't configured any VPN client or server, no openvpn process will run. First configure what you need, then run `service openvpn start`.

Comment: I tried `sudo openvpn  --proto tcp-client --remote x.x.x.x.x.x --port 80  --dev tun1  --secret ovpn.key --redirect-gateway def1 --ifconfig 10.4.0.2 10.4.0.1 --daemon`. And then I issued the command : `service openvpn start`. And I tried with `ps -A | grep -i vpn`. I'm getting no output :( Very much confused! (Note that I have already installed `openvpn` in my server side. Which is the ip I'm passing as `x.x.x.x`)

Comment: Since I'm passing `tun` as network device. I tried this `ifconfig tun1` But I get : `tun1: error fetching interface information: Device not found` error!